# How to create multiple XML elements by the numbers of an int Array in Java

Tags: java, excel, xml

I have been dealing with one algorithm to create an automatic structure of an xml file in Java.

The idea is to count the elements in XML file, put them in a list and then count the repeated elements inside,finally create another XML nodes with the amount of the repeated numbers inside that list.

I solved the first problem by using `Map <String, Long>` and `Collections` to get the repeted elements and number of occurances.

I put them in an Arraylist by converting the number of occurances to int values.

```
Collection test = counterMap.values();
        List <Integer> list = new ArrayList(test);
        Iterator listIteration = list.iterator();
        ArrayList <Integer> intValues = new ArrayList <>();
        while (listIteration.hasNext()) {
            int Values = Integer.parseInt(listIteration.next().toString());
            intValues.add(Values);
        }
```

Now, I have a list of int values `intValues=[1,3,3,4,2,2]` for example.

By using that list, I want to create an XML elements with the numbers of inside this list. I tried for each and for loops to get over it. But I could not.

```
Element example;

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            root = doc.createElement("root");
            pattern.appendChild(root);
            //for (Iterator<Integer> h = intValues.iterator(); h.hasNext();) {
            //Integer item = h.next();
            for (Integer a : intValues) {
                for (int b = 1; b < a; b++) {
                    example = doc.createElement("example");
                    root.appendChild(example);

                }

            }
        }
```

The example output could be:

```
<root>
  <example>
<root>
<root>
  <example>
  <example>
  <example>
<root>
<root>
  <example>
  <example>
  <example>
<root>
<root>
  <example>
  <example>
  <example>
  <example>
<root>
```

(the number of elements as it is in the int arrayList)

Any idea would be nice to move on and Sorry for the mistakes or unclear parts.

**##########SOLUTION UPDATE############**

I found the solution, I add it here so anybody can have it If they eventually cross with the same problem. Thanks for all the help.

```
for (Integer a : intValues) {

            root= doc.createElement("root");

            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {

                pattern.appendChild(root);
                example= doc.createElement("example");
                rule.appendChild(example);

            }
        }
```

this part `for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)`is unnecessary. Just removed it and change a bit order in the loops. The output is exactly what I want.

Comment: Please, add an example of expected XML on the output

Comment: Please have a look at [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: This seems interesting @Lino, thanks a lot.

Comment: Change `int b = 1` to `int b = 0` in your inner loop or change the condition from `b < a` to `b <= a`

Comment: Yes, I tried these changes as well, thanks. The debugging tool shows everything is good. it is as expected. but it creates the number of examples based on the first loop. Which means list.size() amount of example elements for each root.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to all of you once again.

Comment: congrats. you should write an answer and accept it (yes, answer your own question). this will show future users the solution in the most clear way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**##########SOLUTION UPDATE############**

I found the solution, I add it here so anybody can have it If they eventually cross with the same problem. Thanks for all the help.

```
for (Integer a : intValues) {

            root= doc.createElement("root");

            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {

                pattern.appendChild(root);
                example= doc.createElement("example");
                rule.appendChild(example);

            }
        }
```

this part `for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)`is unnecessary. Just removed it and change a bit order in the loops. The output is exactly what I want.